# Monitor setup and desktop background lost on restart

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, external-monitor, desktop-background, xrandr

I have a Lenovo Z570 dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 very happily. I love it, and I'm fairly sure I want to switch permenantly. The laptop has a  1366x768px built in screen, and is connected to a second monitor, resolution 1680x1050px.

At login, both screens are mirrored, and both screens are set to 1024x768px. On logging in, I can set the laptop screen to the correct resolution, but I had to use xrandr in command line to add the correct resolution for the second monitor. I also set a nice desktop background.

On restarting, I get a window saying "Could not apply stored configuration for monitors". It's back to mirroring at 1024x768, and my desktop background is gone.

How can I get the correct resolution at login, keep my desktop background, and not have to mess around in a terminal window every time I reboot?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, it appears the best solution is:

- Not rebooting with the VGA cable plugged in
- Saving the `xrandr` commands to a .sh file to run on startup

I suspect the answer is to get a more modern monitor.